# How do I convert a string into an executable line of code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following bit of code

```
console.log("I am");

var x = "console.log('Alive!')";
```

Now I only want to use `x` to execute the code-string that is assigned to it - I may not even know the value of x for example but simply want to execute it whatever it maybe - is this possible?

Answer (score 43):

[eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) This will convert string to javascript code.

```
eval("console.log('Alive! Woo!')");
```

Answer (score 22):

`eval` and `new Function` let you parse and execute JavaScript code from strings.

In general, avoid executing code from strings. And **never** execute code from strings where the strings are untrusted input (for instance, if you take input from user A, never use these to evaluate it in a session with user B).

I see answers here pointing you at `eval`. `eval` grants access to your local variables and such to the code, making it *really* powerful and *really* dangerous if you use it with untrusted input.

Where possible, avoid `eval`. You can easily avoid it in your case:

For instance:

```js
console.log("I am");
var x = "console.log('Alive!')";
new Function(x)();
```

That code creates a function whose body is the text from `x`, then immediately executes the function.

Answer (score 15):

What you are looking for is `eval()`. By passing a string to this function you will evaluate the string as JavaScript code and it will return whatever return-value the code in the string returns.

Be aware when using this function though. You do not want to evaluate any code you do not know is safe to execute. For example, running user-generated code could mess up whatever you are making. While using this in JavaScript on a website this will probably only cause issues on the client-side and hence probably won't be much of a security threat, you would want to be VERY careful when evaluating code on for example a server side.

As have been hinted to in other posts here you probably want to make a function instead of an evaluated string if you are in control of the source code that is to be run.

Comment: thanks everyone for your replies, that is what I was looking for. problem now is that Im executing the contents of a script that uses document.write and overwrites the whole of the webpage. how can I work around that and simply have the elements appended to the html document and not completely overwrite everything else? gues thats a whole different topi but thanks for your help regarsing the eval question I had!

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a whole new topic but here is a quick explanation of your problem:
`document.write` will always clear the page and create a new when executed after the document have been loaded completely.
Thus you need to use `innerHTML` instead. Fetch an element you would like to edit your content into with something like `document.getElementById()` and do `element.innerHTML = "output"`.

Comment: @AndreasHagen: If there are no DOM nodes on the page, then `document.writeln` writes a single line, without clearing the entire page

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called a *function*:

```
function x() {
    console.log('Alive!');
}
```

If `x` is already a *string* containing the code you could use `eval(x)` to execute it. `eval` is evil though.

Comment: ya but maybe he has a string as an input. Perhaps var fun = new Function("console.log('Alive!')"); then just do:  fun()

Comment: its evil if its in PHP but in javascript everything there is already executable, so...

Answer (score 4):

```
var x = "console.log('Alive!')";
eval(x)
```