# String to number in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When assigning a numerical value to a variable, this code {var x = 1+2+3;} works perfectly but if you if first make it {var x = "1+2+4";} and then later try to use Number(x) to convert it to a number, you get NaN.
Is there a way to to convert the string "1+3+4" into a number and get the answer 8?

Comment: just add a + before the string and check type...like `+"8"`

Comment: @AravindS `+"1+3+4"` is `NaN`.

Comment: If you **really** need dynamic code execution: `var result = new Function("return " + x)();` See [my answer to the dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51047673/157247) for details **and warnings**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, just split the string and add the values to an accumulator using reduce:

```js
let x = "1+3+4";

console.log(x.split("+").reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));
```

Comment: It works provided you have only one type of operator throughout. It doesn't work with multiple operators.

Comment: That's correct, though it's not in the scope of your question. For that you will have to use the answer to the question linked as a dupe